# How to check duplicates value in columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Hi I am using below code to compare my D column value to other column from 5 to 9 for duplicates if any duplicates mark it red color this is working fine.

But how shall i also check the value from column 5 to 9 are also  duplicate if its there it also mark them  color red

```
For col = 5 To 9
TempTest = Ws.Cells(x, col).Value

    If TempTest <> "" Then
       Test = Right(TempTest , Len(TempTest ) - InStrRev(TempTest , ":"))
       Ws.Cells(x, col).Value = Test 
        If Ws.Cells(x, col).Value = Ws.Range("D" & x).Value Then
            Ws.Range("A" & x & ":I" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            y = y + 1
        End If

    End If
Next col
```

Comment: Do you need to do this with VBA? The same thing could be achieved with conditional formatting. What happens if duplicates are in the same column?

Comment: i need to do this with vba only any help

Comment: Does adding `Ws.Range("D" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3` after `Ws.Range("A" & x & ":I" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3` do what you want?

Comment: its comparing only with D column but i have another columns from 5 to 9 which need to be compare with each other

Comment: @kumar  ,, you mean to say that you want to COMPARE both Duplicates & Non Duplicates between Column D  to Column I ,,, if yes what type of data U are using TEXT only,, NUMBERs or both or only DATES ??

Comment: @RajeshS i only want to check Duplicates my column are general texts for ex "AA-BBB-CC" like this

Comment: @kumar  ,,, what about this **But how shall i also check the value from column 5 to 9 are also not duplicate if its there it also mark it duplicate and mark color red**,,, if written by mistake then first [EDit] your post !!

Comment: @RajeshS it was mistake sorry for confusion post edited

Comment: You code is incomplete. You have not given all the information. You are using variables x and y but you have not shown what they represent and their values. Please add the missing details

Comment: @kumar ,,, now check my post ,, I'm sure this is what you were looking for !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little difficult to know exactly what you are after without a sample of your data, but based on your code and the text you have written I think this is on the right track:

```
Option Base 1 'this needs to be at the top of the module
Sub chkdup()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim Chkarr As Variant
        Dim ws1 As Sheet1: Set ws1 = Sheet1
        Dim StartofTable As String, TStr As String
        Dim SRw As Long, SCol As Long, x As Long, y As Long
        StartofTable = "D13" 'enter first cell of table
        Chkarr = ws1.Range(StartofTable).CurrentRegion
        SRw = ws1.Range(StartofTable).Row - 1
        SCol = ws1.Range(StartofTable).Column - 1
        For x = LBound(Chkarr, 2) To UBound(Chkarr, 2)
            For y = LBound(Chkarr, 1) To UBound(Chkarr, 1)
                If InStrRev(Chkarr(y, x), ":") > 0 Then
                    TStr = Right(Chkarr(y, x), Len(Chkarr(y, x)) - InStrRev(Chkarr(y, x), ":"))
                Else
                    TStr = Chkarr(y, x)
                End If
                For i = LBound(Chkarr, 2) To UBound(Chkarr, 2)
                    For j = LBound(Chkarr, 1) To UBound(Chkarr, 1)
                        If x = i And y = j Then GoTo NxtJ
                        If InStr(Chkarr(j, i), ":") > 0 Then
                            If TStr = Right(Chkarr(j, i), Len(Chkarr(j, i)) - InStrRev(Chkarr(j, i), ":")) Then _
                            ws1.Cells(j + SRw, i + SCol).Interior.Color = vbRed
                        Else
                            If Chkarr(j, i) = TStr Then ws1.Cells(j + SRw, i + SCol).Interior.Color = vbRed
                        End If
    NxtJ:
                    Next j
                Next i
            Next y
        Next x
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Change the StartofTable = "D13" to reflect the first cell of your table and it should take care of the rest (it does assume there are no entire blank rows, or entire blank columns, in the table (i.e. there is a contiguous range). The code will highlight any duplicates throughout the table, I included the seperator ":" as an option since it was in your code.

Note that the line:
Option Base 1
needs to go at the top of the module.

A before and after result is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Try this code:*

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet, lr As Long, fVal As Range, c As Range
    
    Set sh = Sheets(3)
    
    lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For Each c In sh.Range("a3:a8")
            
            Set fVal = sh.Range("b3:d" & lr).Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                
                If Not fVal Is Nothing Then
                    fAdr = fVal.Address
                    Do
                    fVal.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    fVal.Value = c.Value
                    Set fVal = sh.Range("b3:d" & lr).FindNext(fVal)
                    Loop While fVal.Address <> fAdr
                End If
        
        Next

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- I've used Command Button to apply the VBA code, you may use simple procedure.
- In this VBA code Sheet Name, Data Range and Color Index are adjustable, modify them as your need.
- If you want to highlight Column A also then change this from
  `sh.Range("b3:d" & lr)` with `sh.Range("A3:d" & lr)` .
- Save the Workbook as Macro Enabled `*.xlsm`.